# angular 6 multiselect dropdown

Tags: typescript, angular6, multi-select

I want to choose the multiple values in angular 6 via the checkbox.
Here i select the department in the dropdown the employees related to the department are listed in the another dropdown with checkbox. This is the process but actually the last value of the array is only displayed on the dropdown I use ng-multiselect-dropdown for selecting multiple values

```
{
   "content":[
      {
         "userid":6,
         "firstName":"Anns Jarigo",
         "lastName":"PaulRaj",
         "jobTitle":"JAVA_DEVELOPER",
         "position":"TEAM_MEMBER",
         "mode_of_employement":"Direct",
         "phoneNumber":"9087881162",
         "date_of_joining":"24-02-2018",
         "reportManager":"sampath.m@binary2quantum.com",
         "image":"anns.jpg",
         "userRole":"EMPLOYEE",
         "appUser":6,
         "department":"JAVA"
      },
      {
         "userid":7,
         "firstName":"Amanullah",
         "lastName":"H",
         "jobTitle":"JAVA_DEVELOPER",
         "position":"TEAM_MEMBER",
         "mode_of_employement":"Direct",
         "phoneNumber":"9087881162",
         "date_of_joining":"14-02-2018",
         "reportManager":"sampath.m@binary2quantum.com",
         "image":"aman.jpg",
         "userRole":"EMPLOYEE",
         "appUser":7,
         "department":"JAVA"
      },
      {
         "userid":8,
         "firstName":"Raj Prabhu",
         "lastName":"A",
         "jobTitle":"JAVA_DEVELOPER",
         "position":"TEAM_MEMBER",
         "mode_of_employement":"Direct",
         "phoneNumber":"9087881162",
         "date_of_joining":"26-07-2018",
         "reportManager":"sampath.m@binary2quantum.com",
         "image":"raj.jpg",
         "userRole":"EMPLOYEE",
         "appUser":8,
         "department":"JAVA"
      },
      {
         "userid":13,
         "firstName":"Subashri",
         "lastName":"P",
         "jobTitle":"JAVA_TRAINEE",
         "position":"INTERN",
         "mode_of_employement":"Direct",
         "phoneNumber":"9087881162",
         "date_of_joining":"17-08-2018",
         "reportManager":"sampath.m@binary2quantum.com",
         "image":"subashri.jpg",
         "userRole":"INTERN",
         "appUser":13,
         "department":"JAVA"
      }
   ],
   "status":"Success!"
}
```

Component.ts

```html
getEmployees(deviceValue: String){
    this.service.getEmployee(deviceValue).subscribe(response=>
  {
    this.employees=response.content;
    
  for(let i = 0 ; i < this.employees.length; i++){
    this.test= this.employees[i].firstName;
    console.log(this.test+" test name")
    this.testId = this.employees[i].userid;
    this.dropdownList=[
        { item_id : this.testId , item_text: this.test}
        ]
}

this.dropdownSettings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      idField:'item_id',
      textField: 'item_text',
      selectAllText: 'Select All',
      unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
      itemsShowLimit: 3,
      allowSearchFilter: true
    };
    
    HTML:
    
    <ng-multiselect-dropdown
    [placeholder]="'custom placeholder'"
    [data]="dropdownList"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
    [settings]="dropdownSettings"
    (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
  >
  </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

`

Comment: When adding things like JSON, please spend few minutes thinking how it would be easier for others to read. If you haven't found them yet, there's plenty of JSON formatters / beautifiers online

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
[placeholder]="'custom placeholder'"
[data]="dropdownList"
[(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
[settings]="dropdownSettings"
(onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
(onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
(click)="onCheck("give your selected details here",$event)"
>
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

> in your component.ts

```
categoryserviceList: Array<Int32Array> = [];

  onCheck(service: any, event) {
  console.log(service, event, "Selected");
  if (event.target.checked) {
    this.categoryserviceList.push(service);

  } else if (!event.target.checked) {
    let index = this.categoryserviceList.indexOf(service);
    this.categoryserviceList.splice(index, 1);
  }
  console.log(this.categoryserviceList);

}
```

> change names based on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
this.dropdownSettings = {
  singleSelection: false,
  idField:'item_id',
  textField: 'item_text',
  selectAllText: 'Select All',
  unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
  itemsShowLimit: 3,
  allowSearchFilter: true
};
```

change the property name here , instead of the extra for loop code you have added.

```
 idField:'testId ',
 textField: 'test',
```